# What are the lines "euler: is urlblocked = false" "firewall not null" in android

Tags: javascript, android, logcat

Whenever I put JavaScript on in a `webview`, run my app using USB on my phone the `LogCat` get spammed with this:

```
  euler: is urlblocked = false
  firewall not null
```

Do you know why?

Comment: I get the same - massive spam that never ends. PITA